# PHP cli from different PHP.ini

Tags: php, bash

I've got a php cli script that I need to execute. However, the CLI version of PHP isn't what I need (the script requires PHP 5.3+ and the CLI version of PHP is only 5.2).

From the command line:

```
# which php
/usr/bin/php


# whereis php
php: /bin/php.orig /bin/php /usr/bin/php.orig /usr/bin/php /sbin/php.orig /sbin/php /usr/sbin/php.orig /usr/sbin/php /etc/php.d /etc/php.ini /lib64/php /usr/lib64/php /usr/local/bin/php.orig /usr/local/bin/php /usr/include/php /usr/share/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

The host tells me I can't change the CLI version of PHP but that I can use a the `php -c` switch to execute the script from another php version. The example they gave was:

```
php –c /root/php/53/etc/php.ini /example/target.php
```

I wrote a shell script like this as a wrapper for the command:

```
#!/bin/bash          
php –c /root/php/53/etc/php.ini /example/target.php
```

However, when I execute the script from the command line I get:

```
Status: 404 Not Found
Content-type: text/html

No input file specified.
```

which makes me think they gave me the path for the apache version of PHP.

Can someone explain what I should be doing here?

Thanks!

Comment: @paulo -- I realize that. I am just using it as a placeholder.

Comment: changing the ini file used does not change the php version used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The php.ini is only the config file, which does not determine the version of PHP that will run. You can check the version by doing `php -v`. If you need to run a different version of php, you'll need to find the php executable. You'll need to contact the host to find out where that executable is, or you can try `whereis php` to find the executable (often located in a bin folder).

Comment: Adding more info above.

Comment: If there are multiple versions of php on the server, they will be in different directories. `which` only shows the version currently used. `whereis` will show all instances of php. Look for the php located in bin folders, and run php -v from those files, ie `usr/local/bin/php -v`

Comment: In your whereis in the post, you have `/bin/php` and `/usr/local/bin/php` other than the version currently used. Ignore the sbins, you most likely won't have access to those. Check the version of the php in those two directories.

Comment: @aynber-- thanks, you're right. More than half of those directories returned `Not a directory` when I attempted to cd into them.

Comment: You don't want to cd into them, just run `/bin/php -v` and `/usr/local/bin/php -v` to find out the versions. If none of those have the version you need, you'll need to talk to your host about installing a new instance of php into a different directory that you can access.